# FTPWebRequest - How to connect without ftp:// in host address?

Tags: c#, ftp

Im creating a module for a scheduled system that needs to execute FTP commands.

The ftp host we are trying to connect to is simply an IP address. i.e below

```
FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("10.1.1.1");
```

When trying to execute this, it complains that it cant define the type of connection, fine when prefixed with ftp:// but then it doesnt resolve as that host does not exist. I am unable to change to host header for the host.

Is there some way to define the Uri as an FTP address without including it in the address? Seems a handy enum would be ideal to identify it as an ftp or http etc.

Or is there another way to connect to an FTP site that I havent found yet?

TIA

Comment: I don't get it. The host is at IP 10.1.1.1 and the protocol is FTP, therefore a URI using the ftp scheme should be fine. What am I missing?

Comment: I think you have to specifically configure a server as an FTP server for this to work - are you sure your "ftp host" is configured for FTP?

Answer (score 5):

Why can you not simply add `ftp://` to the address?

```
FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("ftp://10.1.1.1");
```

`WebRequest` will need the protocol information in order to know what kind of `WebRequest` implementation to create (`WebRequest` is an abstract class that is implemented by `HttpWebRequest` and `FtpWebRequest`).

Comment: I was confused and taking the protocol as part of the address. Essentially there was a big weird proxy in the way, and FtpWebRequest just wasnt ablwe to handle it. Found a decent library that wraps wininet api and am using that instead without an issue. Cheers for help